# Is there a pramana to know the existence of the pramanas?

Tags: pramana

In the Vedic epistemology (theory of knowledge), there are three [pramanas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pramana) (means of knowledge):

1. Pratyaksha (perception, experience, memory, etc.)
2. Anumana (logic, inference, reasoning, etc.)
3. Shabda (testimony of trustworthy persons)

These are the means of knowledge. Knowledge in Vedic epistemology is "valid cognition": a cognition that gives information about the external world. So the pramanas are means of valid cognition. An invalid cognition is something like imagination. It's invalid because it doesn't give any information about the world since it is made up in one's mind. Illusion, hallucination, etc. are also invalid cognitions.

But how is the existence of these pramanas known? Is there another pramana separate from these 3?

To me, it seems like the existence of these pramanas is known through pratyaksha, since all these pramanas are directly experienced. But if pratyaksha as a pramana is established through pratyaksha itself, then it's a circular argument.

But the invalidity of a circular argument is only valid if we accept that anumana is a pramana. But what's the pramana to show that anumana is a pramana?

Well, Hindu scriptures, rishis, and other trustworthy people told me that anumana and pratyaksha are pramanas. So, they must be pramanas. But again, I can only believe this if I accept shabda as a pramana. But what is there to show that shabda is a pramana?

So, it actually seems like these pramanas are accepted [axiomatically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom).

Comment: very easy - do not accept anything as pramana. then the next moment you do anything in life (whether breathing/seeing/eating), you'll realize pratyaksha pramana does not require anyone else to prove it to you, it is self-evident. a little while later, you'll realize that pratyaksha is unreliable (snake vs. rope), and that anumana is also unreliable. and bhagavan has setup the universe in such a way, that at some point in your existence, you will hear shabda. and you'll realize shabda is also unreliable. unless that shabda comes from one source. and that source is always reliable eternally.

Comment: There are ten pramanas: Pratyaksha, Anumana, Shabda, Upamana, Arthapatti, Anupalabdhi, Aitihya, Sambhava, Chesta and Parishesha. Advaita and followers of Kumaralila school accept six.

Comment: Pratyaksha and Anumana are to be accepted axiomatically. They can't be proved to you. Infact giving proof means giving Pratyaksha and Anumana only. Just like modern mathematics has axioms. Epistemology also has empirical and logical proof as axioms